# print hexadecimal representation of an int

Tags: string, integer, pseudocode

i am looking for a pseudocode that prints the hexadecimal represenation of an integer as string.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take the remainder of the integer modulo 16
- Convert the remainder to a hex digit
- Place the hex digit into the left-most position in the output string
- Divide the integer by 16
- Repeat the above until the value is zero